# Generating CSS Classname based on Model Property Value

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

**Background:**

> I have a floorplan image of an exhibition hall. I will be using CSS to
>   generate small colored rectangle that marks the floorplan where the
>   booths are removed.
>
> Each booth is stored in my ExhibitorBooth which consists of
>   ID,Status,CSS_Top and CSS_Left. CSS_Top and Left are positions where
>   the colored rectangle should be. Status decides if that rectangle
>   should appear.

[image: Example of the floorplan]

Now to my problem. I am trying to generate the CSS class named after the database **boothCode** data using the foreach loop. My current code does not work because of my lack of knowledge of razor syntax

```
<style>

@foreach (var booths in @Model.ExhibitorBooths)
{
     @:.@booths.Id
    {
        @: top: @booths.CSS_Top px;
        @: left: @booths.CSS_Left px;
    }
}
</style>
```

We have done it previously using Classic ASP with this being the code.

```
<% rs.open "select * from exhibitionBooth order by boothId", cn
do until rs.eof %>
#floorplan #<%=rs("boothCode")%> 
{
    top: <%=rs("css_top")%>px; 
    left: <%=rs("css_left")%>px; 
}
<%
    rs.moveNext
loop
rs.close
%>
```

This code worked but we could not emulate the same effect using Razor Syntax. Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable than I am will be able to help with this.

Comment: Why not just do it using inline styles?

Comment: That is actually ingenious Stephen. Could you post as an answer so I can mark you as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<text>` tags,

```
@foreach (var booths in @Model.ExhibitorBooths)
{
    <text>
        .@booths.Id {
            top: @booths.CSS_Top px;
            left: @booths.CSS_Left px;
        }
    </text>
}
```

But this would be easier if you just used in-line styles. Rather than separate properties for top and left, include one `string Position` property in your model to use in a `style` attribute and format the value. For example, in the controller

```
booth.Position = string.Format("top:{0}px; left:{1}px"; top, left);
```

And then in the view, to generate your `<div>`

```
@foreach (var booths in Model.ExhibitorBooths)
{
    <div style="@booth.Position" .....> 
}
```